# Aside from the part of the timestamp, how to ensure that the compilation gives us the same dll file from one computer to another?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dll, compilation, compare

I compile a dll on two different computers with the same compiler version in C++ Visual Studio 2008. The source code is the same on two computers. Unfortunately, the dll is different from one computer to another but the size is the same. Does anyone can tell me why? Aside from the part of the timestamp, how to ensure that the compilation gives us the same dll file from one computer to another?

Thank you!

Comment: Different in what way? Just different hash values or generated code? Note that the timestamp when it is built is also stored in the COFF header in the DLL which will affect the hash. If only the timestamp is changing the file will be the same size but have a different hash value.

Comment: The two files are different in many places but they have the same size. The associated map files are different too with same functions but at different adresses.